# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'children'

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm working with algorithms and graphs, this is the section of the code that seems to be the problem:

```
256, in search: pf = Astar(self.map.children, self.map.move_cost,
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'children'
```

I really don't understand why the error shows up, as children is clearly defined in Astar too. I've passed nrows, ncols and goal to Grid so that's ok too.

Comment: Didn't you meant to use `self.children(self.map)` ?

Comment: @DimitriMockelyn I tried doing that earlier but it spit out but then I had an error on 'newrow = c[0] + drow' where it could only join a list to a list, not a list to an int.

Answer (score 1):

It seems self.map contains a list, at the time when you are passing 'self.map.children' as an argument when instantiating Astar class.

Answer (score 0):

In your code self.map is a list `self.map = [[0] * self.ncols for i in range(self.nrows)]`. Lists have no attribute children that can be accessed.